# Euler transform of a series

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

i want to prove some identity but i am having trouble using euler transform properly on a specific function, i checked the equality and it doesnt hold, here is the theorem and my approach. THeorem.
$$\frac{1}{1-at}f\left(\frac{bt}{1-at}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}t^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}b^{k}a^{n-k}a_{k}$$
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}t^{n}$$
Where f is analytiic on a unit disk.
I want to apply this transformation to a function given as follows
$$\frac{1}{4}\ln ^{2}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{h_{n}}{n}x^{2n}$$
Where $h_{n}=\sum_{p=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2p-1}$.
What i get is
$$\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1-at}\ln ^{2}\left(\frac{1+\frac{bt}{1-at}}{1-\frac{bt}{1-at}}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}\frac{h_{k}}{k}b^{k}a^{n-k}$$
I checked it for $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$ and for $t=\frac{1}{3}$ and it doesnt hold. Please point out the mistake and help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the inner sum of $k$ why is that it can be odd? in the generating function $a_k=0$ for $k$ odd.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail. What do you mean, can you write it please? What do you think should be a correct result.